# Data is not well clusterd with any clustering approach

Tags: cluster-analysis

When I cluster my data (with any clustering approach) and compute the quality metrics (I tried several metrics, silhouette, Dunn, etc), I get very poor scores.
What I'm interested in is that whether my data is clusterable or not? Is there any methods to assess that? Or a method telling me if the data contain any useful information?
Thanks,
Hamid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it *just* doesn't have clusters?

Or they do not fit to the model *evaluated* by Silhouette, Dunn etc. - these metrics can be quite misleading, in particular when you have noise in your data set, too. Don't blindly trust such metrics.

The best way of seeing if your data can be clustered is *visualization*. If you can't visualize it in a way you see clusters, how can you expect an algorithm to return meaningful clusters?